# ObjectPicker doesn't work for a dynamically created entity if there isn't already another entity with ObjectPicker

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I have a `Scene3D` where I dynamically add an entity which has an `ObjectPicker`, via this helper class' `Scene3DViewHelper::addCuboid()` slot:

scene3dviewhelper.h:

```
#ifndef SCENE3DVIEWHELPER_H
#define SCENE3DVIEWHELPER_H

#include <Qt3DCore/QEntity>

class Scene3DViewHelper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_PROPERTY(Qt3DCore::QEntity * rootEntity READ rootEntity WRITE setRootEntity NOTIFY rootEntityChanged)

    explicit Scene3DViewHelper(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity * rootEntity() const;

public slots:
    void setRootEntity(Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity);
    void addCuboid();

signals:
    void rootEntityChanged(Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity);

private:
    Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity_;
};

#endif // SCENE3DVIEWHELPER_H
```

scene3dviewhelper.cpp:

```
#include "scene3dviewhelper.h"
#include <Qt3DCore>
#include <Qt3DRender>
#include <Qt3DExtras>

Scene3DViewHelper::Scene3DViewHelper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

Qt3DCore::QEntity * Scene3DViewHelper::rootEntity() const { return rootEntity_; }

void Scene3DViewHelper::setRootEntity(Qt3DCore::QEntity *rootEntity)
{
    auto old = rootEntity_;
    rootEntity_ = rootEntity;
    if(rootEntity_ != old) emit rootEntityChanged(rootEntity);
}

void Scene3DViewHelper::addCuboid()
{
    if(!rootEntity_) return;
    auto cuboidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity_);
    auto mat = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(cuboidEntity);
    mat->setDiffuse(QColor(217, 217, 255));
    auto t = new Qt3DCore::QTransform(cuboidEntity);
    auto mesh = new Qt3DExtras::QCuboidMesh(cuboidEntity);
    auto picker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker(cuboidEntity);
    connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::clicked, [=] {
        qDebug() << "clicked entity" << cuboidEntity;
    });
    mesh->setXExtent(1);
    mesh->setYExtent(1);
    mesh->setZExtent(1);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(mat);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(t);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(mesh);
    cuboidEntity->addComponent(picker);
}
```

Scene3DView.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.14
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Logic 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

import Qt3DUtils 1.0

Scene3D {
    id: scene3d
    aspects: ["render", "logic", "input"]
    hoverEnabled: true // needed for ObjectPickers to handle hover events
    property alias helper: helper
    
    data: Scene3DViewHelper {
        id: helper
        rootEntity: rootEntity
    }

    entity: Entity {
        id: rootEntity
        components: [
            RenderSettings {
                ForwardRenderer {
                    id: forwardRenderer
                    camera: mainCamera
                }
                pickingSettings.pickMethod: PickingSettings.TrianglePicking
                pickingSettings.pickResultMode: PickingSettings.AllPicks
                pickingSettings.faceOrientationPickingMode: PickingSettings.FrontAndBackFace
            },
            InputSettings {}
        ]
    
        Camera {
            id: mainCamera
            projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
            fieldOfView: 45
            aspectRatio: 16/9
            nearPlane : 0.1
            farPlane : 1000.0
            position: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.0, -4.0)
            upVector: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            viewCenter: Qt.vector3d(0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
        }

        /*Entity {
            id: cuboid0
            components: [
                CuboidMesh {
                    xExtent: 1
                    yExtent: 1
                    zExtent: 1
                },
                Transform {
                    translation.x: -1.5
                },
                PhongMaterial {
                    diffuse: Qt.rgba(0.85, 0.85, 1, 1)
                },
                ObjectPicker {
                    onClicked: console.log("clicked entity", cuboid0)
                }
            ]
        }*/
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.13 as QtQuick
    
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 700

    MainMenu {
        onAddCuboid: scene3d.helper.addCuboid()
    }

    Scene3DView {
        id: scene3d
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "scene3dviewhelper.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<Scene3DViewHelper>("Qt3DUtils", 1, 0, "Scene3DViewHelper");
    const QUrl mainUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [&](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if(!obj && mainUrl == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(mainUrl);
    return app.exec();
}
```

The problem is that the `ObjectPicker` doesn't work: I'm supposed to see the "clicked entity Qt3DCore::QEntity(0x7fa19f005300)" message on the console when I click the cuboid, but I don't see it.

If I uncomment the `cuboid0` entity, then picking works both for the `cuboid0` entity and for the dynamically created cuboid:

> qml: clicked entity Qt3DCore::Quick::Quick3DEntity(0x7fa0d7c025e0)
>
> clicked entity Qt3DCore::QEntity(0x7fa0d6527f10)

What does creating the Entity in QML do that I don't do in `void Scene3DViewHelper::addCuboid()`?

Comment: Does it happen for `pressed` signal too? Using `connect(picker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::pressed, ...);`

Comment: Yes, also `pressed` is not received if the static (*cuboid0*) entity is not present. Strangely, if *cuboid0* is present, `pressed` is received twice on the dynamically created entity.

Comment: Another interesting fact is that is enough to add *cuboid0* with `enabled: false`, and picking will work on the dynamically created entity.

Comment: What's the Qt version you are using - 5.14.1? Can you try to build against 5.13.2? Does that change behaviour? I was facing something similar like https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-82269 but did not nail it down to the exact reason.

Comment: I think @vre is right. Try Qt LTS versions like `5.12.7` and see if behavior is the same.

Comment: Right. I tried with 5.12.5 and it does not happen.

Comment: Removing `hoverEnabled: true` makes the issue go away